# When and how to use StringBuilder/Buffer efficiently?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I want to create a string which is made by concatenating about 3000 other strings.
I hear that using so many strings can be inefficient because they lie in some kind of 
pool and may not be picked up by the GC immediately after they are not needed.

Is this the best way to go about it -

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

for(String s : arrayWith3000Strings)
{
  sb.append(s);
}
```

or should i concatenate all the strings into one string ?

Comment: You can do `new StringBuilder()` instead of `new StringBuilder("")`

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder. There is almost never a good reason to sue StringBuffer.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a case where StringBuilder is preferred.

Strings are "immutable".  Any operation that modifies a string (including "append") creates a new string.  Using stringbuilder avoids that expense.

This link (one of many) explains further:

- http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/07/string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Your code is good.

Even though you use String concatenation it creates new `String objects` because Strings are immutable.

Comment: - Yes, there will be many strings because of that.
What if i do it using concat instead ? Will there be any difference ?

Comment: concat is operation on String, all operations on String results in new String, so that is not good way to handle this. Your code is optimal way.

Comment: thanks...is there also a graphical way to show and compare these methods with iterations = 100,000 ?

Comment: May be you can get timings, but to be frank I am not aware of any graphical tools for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

`StringBuffer` has even better performance than `StringBuilder`, but `StringBuffer` is not thread-safe!

EDIT: of course, it is vice versa :)

Comment: And `StringBuilder` usually performs the best out of the two.

Comment: ...because it doesn't have the overhead of synchronized methods.

Comment: I don't think i need multithreading for now, so string buffer may not be the best choice. Apparently, its much slower than string builder

Comment: @Breadbutter It is slow in cycle-intensive applications (where it is used millions of times).

Comment: @jsn - yes, i will be doing a 3000 count cycle on it.